# How to catch NonexistentConversationException

Tags: jsf, query-string, cdi, conversation-scope

I have a link as follows:

```
<h:link outcome="/Pages/Public/producthome.jsf?cid=6">cagtegoryName</h:link>
```

When I want to try pass the category ID by URL, it shows the following error:

> WELD:00032 conversation not found for restoring id 1

If I just simply write the link as follows

```
<h:link outcome="/Pages/Public/producthome.jsf">categoryName</h:link>
```

then it works fine. What did I wrong in the first link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the url param name `cid` is recognized as `conversationId`. Please try changing the name of the parameter. For an example

```
<h:link outcome="/Pages/Public/producthome.jsf?catid=6">cagtegoryName</h:link>
```